# CDI Interceptor does not work when defined and used in bean archive (jar)

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-6, cdi, interceptor

I have the following project structure (Maven):

```
- war with `WEB-INF/beans.xml`, `WEB-INF/web.xml` and REST service configuration
- ext-spi (packaged as jar, not bean archive) which provides some simple SPI, finally goes to `war/WEB-INF/lib`  
- ext - parent project (pom)  
-- ext-impl (jar, bean archive - META-INF/beans.xml exists) - contains CDI Interceptor (both binding and implementation) + some REST service (RequestScoped CDI Bean) which is annotated with mentioned Interceptor Binding finally goes to `war/WEB-INF/lib`  
-- ext-model (jar) - contains REST service API and data model, finally goes to `war/WEB-INF/lib`
```

And the problem is that Interceptor simply does not work. Of course I have enabled it in `beans.xml` (different combinations with `war` and `ext-impl`). No errors, no warnings.
It looks like `META-INF/beans.xml` is not even read from jar - no complains about fake classpath which I gave when enabling interceptor or even malformed xml tags. The same CDI Bean has no issues when `@Inject`ing another CDI Bean from the same bean archive.

If I try to use the same Interceptor on some CDI Bean created directly in `war` - everything works perfectly.

According to spec it should work.

**Application Server:** Glassfish 3.1.2.2

**Interceptor:**

```
@Inherited  
@InterceptorBinding  
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })  
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  
public @interface ResourceInterceptorBinding {
}
```

Do you have any idea what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks and giggles try adding it the war beans.xml and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, already tried it: _Of course I have enabled it in beans.xml (different combinations with war and ext-impl)_. Did not help at all ;/.

Comment: How are you instantiating the intercepted bean?

Comment: What we are talking about is a REST service. I am using `jersey` and it goes as follows:

Intercepted bean is defined in `ext-impl`:
`@Path("jobs")
@RequestScoped
@ResourceInterceptorBinding
public class HpcJobsService implements HpcJobsApi {`

Then service is registered in extension descriptor:
`@ServiceProvider( service = ServiceDescriptor.class)
public class ExtServiceDescriptor implements ServiceDescriptor {
        serviceClasses.add(HpcJobsService.class);`

Comment: and finally implementation of javax.ws.rs.core.Application that sets up all services.


`public class RestService extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return serviceClasses;
    }`

Comment: Funny thing I use exactly the same mechanism for some other services defined in `war` and, of course, it works. That is why I do not think the issue is in how beans are instantiated. But thanks for trying :).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested: looks like it is a Glassfish bug. I have just found the following Jira issue: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18802

Edit: It is even worse - I had to enable the interceptor in ALL bean archives that can be found under `META-INF\lib`. Otherwise it simply does not work.